# Timestamp literal in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, ojdbc

I need to test sql queries on *Oracle SQL Developer*.
These queries contain timestamp literals in the format

`{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'}`

*Oracle SQL Developer* does not seem to accept this syntax, the symbol `{` causes error **ORA-00911: invalid character**.

Is there anything I can do?

**EDIT**

The sql editor advises me that `{` is not allowed.
I tried with two other tools (*DbVisualizer* and *DBeaver*), both using the *Oracle Thin* driver, all works fine.

However I still want to use that syntax in *Oracle SQL Developer* because it has interesting features.
The queries I have to test are not written by me, change syntax is not an option.

Comment: That error is not from SQL Developer, is from Oracle itself. Search "oracle timestamp literal" to get info on how to write that literals.

Comment: SQL Developer simply turns off the JDBC escape processing in the JDBC driver, that's the reason you can't use `{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'}`. There is nothing you can do in SQL Developer. And Oracle doesn't care and claims it isn't a bug: https://community.oracle.com/message/14068970#14068970

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yours is the only useful answer

Answer (score 11):

Use an actual SQL timestamp literal:

```
TIMESTAMP 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'
```

What you were using is the [JDBC escape syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#JJDBC28913), which is supported by JDBC drivers, but not by the Oracle database itself.

Comment: SQL Developer doesn't support JDBC escapes, because it turns off the escape processing in the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CAST`

```
select to_char(cast(sysdate as timestamp),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual
```

Comment: `cast(sysdate as timestamp)` is useless

Answer (score 0):

See the answer of : [How to convert date to timestamp(DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF format) in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329483/how-to-convert-date-to-timestampdd-mon-yyyy-hh24miss-ff-format-in-oracle)

The "{ts xxx}" syntax is specific to ODBC or OLEDB driver...

Answer (score 0):

issue with using timestamp literals in the specific format `{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'}` in Oracle SQL . The curly braces `{}` are not standard SQL syntax and might be causing the error you're encountering.

you can use the standard ANSI SQL timestamp literal format without the curly braces. Here's how you can format your timestamp literal:

```sql
TIMESTAMP 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'
```

example

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE timestampcolumn >= TIMESTAMP '2023-08-29 12:34:56.789';
```

If the queries you're working with were written using the specific `{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'}` syntax, you might need to replace it with the standard ANSI SQL timestamp literal format to ensure compatibility with Oracle SQL.